# Create a instance for a JSON and access the values in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have a use case where I need to create an instance variable for the below JSON object and access the values of it using the get method

```
{
  "id" : "12345",
  "pid" : "a245vkkb",
  "fid" : "9087hbnh"
}
```

I have the code which returns the above JSON values. Is there any way to create an instance for that in one class and use (eg: pid), getPID() to fetch the pid value in KOTLIN? Which should only return the pid value.

Comment: Probably I don't completely understand the problem, but a convenient way to load a JSON data to a data class instance is to use Jackson `ObjectMapper::readValue()` method like this: `val config = mapper.readValue(inputStream, Config::class.java)!!`

Comment: If I understand correctly you don't want create a model class for a json. In your case your have key-value pairs and you can use map. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567865/how-to-iterate-key-value-pair-in-retrofit/43568563#43568563

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using gson library.

**Maven Dependency**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can get this into a either map or object.

**As Map**

```
val data = Gson().fromJson(<json-string>, Map::class.java) as Map<String, String>
```

**As Object** (if you certain about json fields)

```
data class Foo (
    val id: String,
    val pid: String,
    val fid: String
)

val data = Gson().fromJson(<json-string>, Foo::class.java)
```

You can also use `TypeToken` to do this

```
val data = Gson().fromJson(<json-string>, object: TypeToken<Foo>() {}.type)
```